# Reading a text file and updating values in php

Tags: php, forms, text-files

I am creating a webpage where users can log in and then edit information about themselves that is in a form. I read the data to be inserted into the form from a text file separated by ":" I cannot get the file to edit existing values.

```
    <form name="edit" action="info.php" method="get">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $arr[2]; ?>"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $arr[3]; ?>"><br>
    Background color: <input type="text" name="bgcolor" value="<?php echo $arr[4]; ?>"><br>
    Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $arr[5]; ?>"><br>
    Image: <input type="text" name="bgimg" value="<?php echo $arr[6]; ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="editUpdate" value="true">
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="Edit account info" />
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['editUpdate'])) {
    $open = fopen('account-info.txt', "r+");
    $firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];
    $bgcolor = $_REQUEST['bgcolor'];
    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $bgimg = $_REQUEST['bgimg'];
    fwrite($open, $firstName, $lastName, $bgcolor, $title, $bgimg);
    fclose($open);
    $login = true;
    }
```

Comment: change   $open = fopen('assignment11-acount-info.txt', "r+"); into   $open = fopen('assignment11-acount-info.txt', "w+");

Comment: that solution worked ?

Comment: That deleted everything out of my text file. I want to keep what is in the text file, just change the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure fields don't have the sentinel value**

Validate all input  Always. In this case, strip any HTML tags using `htmlentities` function, and prevent the sentinel value (`:`) you use in storage from being in any of the fields.

**Locking**

You need to acquire a mutex, semaphores or lock. This lock should be used any time the file is being written to (new users or user updates).  Not doing this will allow a race condition.

There are lots of different types of locks, but PHP provides a pretty simple interface for that with the flock function: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

**Read**

Then, you need to open the file for read.
Read all the users into a multi dimensional array:

```
 $users = file_get_contents ('account-info.txt');
 $users = explode('\n',$users);
 for($user_index = 0;count(users) > $user_index;++$user_index)
 {
   $users[$user_index] = explode(':',$users);
 }
```

**Update the array**

You'll need to find the right record to update.  This will likely necessitate another field, an user id number or username that can't change; or else, holding onto their old first and last name. I leave this to you figure out.

**Write the array back to the file**
Loop through the array and write them all back out.

```
$fp = fopen('account-info.txt', "w+");
foreach($users as $user)
{
  foreach($user as field)
  {
    fwrite($fp,$field . ':');
  }
  fwrite($fp,"\n");
}
close($fp);
```

**Release locks**

Release any and all mutex, semaphores, and/or locks in the reverse order that they are acquired to prevent deadlock situations.

If you have choice about the file format, PHP has better functions for reading and writing serialized files, json, CSV and XML files than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
$open = fopen('account-info.txt', "a+");
```

mode `a+` will Open file for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

for more detail look at [PHP fopen function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)